# usb printer and stm32F4 host communication

Tags: printing, usb, stm32

I want to interface my printer with my stm32F407VGT6 board, and I don't know which usb driver library to choose (OTG/DEVICE/HOST).
I want to send / receive microcontroller commands to the printer.

thank you in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the USB host library, or the OTG (On The Go) library which allows you to be host or device. You should also take care that you are using the right library for your chip.